# Why do certain pip libraries require elevated access while their conda counterparts don't?

Tags: python, pip, conda

Let's say I'm in a conda environment in a remote server, where I don't have elevated access.

Now, I want to install a library from pip, I take librosa as an example

```
pip install librosa
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'ilike/trains/miniconda3/envs/mwe_regex_2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
```

Then the usually work around would be pip install --user, which would install the libraries on the global level, which is not so desirable. However, what made me think is that the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge librosa
```

is that this installs without any hickup. Then I realised that this makes sense, as conda just probably downloads a static build of the cffi binary. However with libraries like pyasn1, I get a similar error

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tudelft.net/staff-bulk/ewi/insy/SpeechLab/bhalpern/miniconda3/envs/espnet_env_conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyasn1-0.4.8.dist-info/INSTALLERidmrvd4t.tmp'
```

which seems to go away with a repeated install.

So my questions are

- If I can't install a library from conda (because it's not in conda). and the pip version needs a binary, is my only option to use pip install --user?
- what are these TMPs and why do they require elevated access? Why do they go away with repeated pip install?

Comment: have you tried pip install --user librosa`

Comment: I have tried and it would solve it. But my question is of more general applicability: sure, a conda install solves this problem if we have the library in conda. Sure, if we have unlimited space for user-level installs on a remote server, pip install --user is a good solution. I propose that the answer partially lies in the pre-compiled binaries which don't need then the user-level elevation (see so error). Basically, I want to understand what features exactly need the elevation of access rights and what I can do to prevent this (apart from installing on user level).

Comment: could it be that conda is running at local level instead of global, namely the base environment or whatever environment the user is in?

Answer (score 1):

`conda` does everything in "user" space, like your home directory (just like `pip --user`), whereas `pip` (without virtual environments) defaults to doing things in "system" space.

> If I can't install a library from conda (because it's not in conda). and the pip version needs a binary, is my only option to use pip install --user?

One option is to just migrate the PyPI package to conda, using a tool like [`conda skeleton`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html#building-a-simple-package-with-conda-skeleton-pypi). But short of that, `pip` installing a package into a conda env puts it into that env, which again is in user space. (Make sure you are using the `pip` that is provided with conda, something like `/path/to/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin/pip`, instead of the global `pip`, which will probably install things outside of it, defeating the purpose).